# $\sigma$-algebra of all countable sets in interval

Tags: measure-theory

I was wondering if my approach was correct :
**The question :**
Given interval $[0,1]$ and set $A$ = {all finite and countable subsets of the interval} , what is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$ ?

**My try:**
First , lets look at the $1$-element sets - we have $\omega_1$ sets  like this with their complements.
If we look at the $2$-element set and so on we can easily see that we always have the same relation -
Cardinality of the set = $\omega_0$ and cardinality of the complement is $\omega_1$.
So my assumption is - The $\sigma$-algebra generated from the countable sets is
$$\{X \quad | \quad |X|=\omega_0 \vee |X^c|=\omega_0\}$$

But I failed to prove it -
I tried to assume there exist some set generated by the $\sigma$-algebra with the property :
$|X|=\omega_1 \wedge |X|=\omega_1$

Am I correct and I just need to find a way to prove it or I'm wrong ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not quite: For instance the empty set must be in the sigma algebra, but it’s not there in your set.

Comment: Answer: All sets that are at most countable and the complements  of such sets.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I added an answer to that effect.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  sorry I wrote with a typo - I meant $A$ to be all the finite subsets and of $\omega_0$ cardinality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite: The problem is that your set does *not* contain complements which are finite.For instance it does not contain the empty set, yet we have:  $[0,1]^c=\varnothing$.So your set is *not* a sigma-algebra(since sigma-algebras are closed under complements).
So the answer to your question needs to be slightly tweaked, namely the sigma algebra generated by the set of all countable subsets of $[0,1]$, is the subset $\sigma$ of $[0,1]$ such that elements of $
\sigma$ are exactly those elements of $[0,1]$ which are **at most** countable *or* are complements of **at most** countable sets. It’s easy to check that $\sigma$ is a sigma-algebra and that it is the *smallest* sigma-algebra containing the set of all countable subsets of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I forgot to mention the finite sets too (so $A$ includes the empty set and all the finite ones and all the $\omega_0$ cardinality.)